# window.open("c:\test.txt") from Silverlight

Tags: javascript, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I'm trying to open local file from Silverlight. I try Window.Navigate("c:\test.pdf", "_blank") and invoking JavaScript like this:

```
window.open("c:\test.pdf", "_blank")
```

Both give "Access is denied".

However it works in plain HTML when I do

```
<input type="button" value="test" 
       onclick="window.open('c:\test.pdf', '_blank')" />
```

Is it Silverlight security restriction? Can I open a local file in a browser from Silverlight application?

The reason behind this is that users store local paths and want to open those files from the app.

Comment: Imagine all the evil things you could do if there was no such security restriction.

Comment: OK but JavaScript can do this. Is it so different when I open browser window from pure JavaScript versus JavaScript called from Silverlight?

Comment: Could it be that it works when your page is run from file://c:/yada yada/script.html but not when you test from http://yadayada.com/script.html

Comment: Yes you're right. Stupid mistake of not reproducing exact environment. OK, no luck then.

Answer (score 3):

Silverlight is heavily sandboxed.  As it is a web technology, you can probably imagine the potential security implications of giving it access to the file system.

Comment: I actually can't imaging any implications. JavaScript is also a web technology, as well as <a href="file:///c:\test.pdf"> but they do work.

Answer (score 0):

In Silverlight 4, you have access in the local file system, but to the user's "My" folders only.  See http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/11/18/whats-new-in-silverlight-4-complete-guide-new-features.aspx#localfiles